# How to enable auto close tag with prettier in vs code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, prettier

I want to enable auto close empty tag with Prettier in Visual Studio Code v 1.37.1.

I want this:

```
<img src='/logo.svg' alt='' />
<div />
```

from this:

```
<img src='/logo.svg' alt=''>
<div></div>
```

Anyone knows where to enable it in Prettier or with any other extension ??

Comment: i know… it's not answer, but do you really need it? Because then it's not valid html5 … element div must be closed with `</div>`

Comment: Why it's not valid ?

Comment: Per HTML 5 specifications the div element will need a closing tag. See [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had problem with emmet from vs code. When I set this to html my img tags were looking like this:

```
<img src='' alt=''>
```

And I couldn't save document without having a prettier error.

After set this in setting.json in vscode:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact"
    },
```

When I write `img` and press tab, I'm getting this:

```
<img src='' alt='' />
```

And divs stays like they should look like:

```
<div></div>
```